# C code won't run on mac but runs on windows

Tags: c

Basically, we made a neural network that tests if a digit from a digital clock is odd or even.
The C code works on my windows machine, however, it gives me a lot of errors on my mac.
Like: **function definition is not allowed here**.

I think it's just a compilation issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#define ligne 10
#define colonne 8

int main (){
    
    //--------------------------creation A, W, O, d, X, epsilon--------------------------
    int i,j;
    float epsilon    =   0.2;
    float cpt_A;
    int   O[ligne]; 
    float A[ligne];
    float W[colonne];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for( i = 0 ; i < colonne ; i++ ) {
        W[i]=rand() % 6;
    }
    int   d[ligne]   =   {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
    int   X[ligne][colonne]= {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1}};

    //--------------------------Check for O--------------------------
    int check(float a){
        if(a>=0) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    //--------------------------Remplissage de A[]--------------------------
    float* Remplissage_A(float A[],float nW[],int index ){
        for(i=index ; i<ligne ; i++){
            for(j=0 ; j<colonne ; j++){
                cpt_A += nW[j]*X[i][j];
            }
            A[i]=cpt_A;
        }
        return A;
    }

    //--------------------------Fonction check pour remplir O--------------------------
    int* Remplissage_O(float A[]){

        for ( i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
            O[i]=check(A[i]);
        }
        return O;
    }

    //--------------------------Affichage X--------------------------
    for(i=0; i<colonne; i++){
        printf("X%d\t",i);
    }
    printf("Valeur\n");
    for(i=0; i<ligne; i++){
        for(j=0; j<colonne; j++){
            printf("%d",X[i][j]);
            printf(j<colonne-1?"\t":"    =>   %d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //printf("%f\n",A[i]);
    }
        
    //--------------------------Print A et O et d--------------------------
    printf("\nA\t");printf("O\t");printf("D\n");
    float *Ax= Remplissage_A(A,W,0);
    int *Ox= Remplissage_O(A);
    for ( i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
        printf("%.1f\t",*(Ax + i));printf("%d\t",*(Ox + i));printf("%d\n",d[i]);
    }

    //--------------------------Fonction Correction W --------------------------
    void Correction_W(int index){

        for(j=0;j<colonne;j++){
            W[j]=W[j]+(epsilon*((d[index]-O[index])*X[index][j]));
        }
    }
    //--------------------------Fonction Correction--------------------------
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");


    void Correction(float *A,float *W,int *O){
        int stop=0;
        int allCorrect= false;
        int i,index;
        A=Remplissage_A(A,W,0);
        O=Remplissage_O(A);
        while (!allCorrect){
            for ( i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
                if(d[i]!=O[i]){
                    index=i;
                    Correction_W(index);
                    A = Remplissage_A(A,W,index);
                    O = Remplissage_O(A);
                    stop++;
                }
            }
            if(stop==0){
                allCorrect=true;
            }
            stop=0;
        }
    }

    //--------------------------Appel Fonction--------------------------
    Correction(A,W,O);

    //--------------------------Apres correction--------------------------
    printf("Apres correction : \n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nA\t");printf("O\t");printf("D\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
        printf("%.1f\t",*(A + i));
        printf("%d\t",*(O + i));
        printf("%d\n",d[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: The C standard does not allow nested functions. But some compilers allow nested functions as an extension. I see no benefit in having all of your functions *inside* of the `main` function. Just move them outside of the `main` function.

Comment: Please post all the error messages that you are getting as text into the question.

Comment: Aside, why are 3 `printf()` used where only 1 is required? `printf("%.1f\t",*(Ax + i));printf("%d\t",*(Ox + i));printf("%d\n",d[i]);`

Comment: `cpt_A` is not initialized.

Comment: It gives me a lot of errors. It would be intgeresting to see *which are these errors*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (main issue) I changed your nested functions to, well, non-nested functions.  You may not like the order of arguments that I chose.
2. `Remplissage_A()`: I initialized  `cpt_A = 0`.  Please check that this is what you want.
3. `main()`: Fixed the conditional print to silence warning about one of the strings not having a matching format for variable being passed in.
4. `check()`: refactored then inlined.
5. Minimized scope of variables (i, j, size, cpt_A, etc).
6. Combined consecutive `printf()` calls.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ligne 10
#define colonne 8

//--------------------------Remplissage de A[]--------------------------
float* Remplissage_A(float A[],float nW[], int X[ligne][colonne], int index) {
    float cpt_A = 0;
    for(int i=index ; i<ligne ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<colonne ; j++){
            cpt_A += nW[j]*X[i][j];
        }
        A[i]=cpt_A;
    }
    return A;
}

//--------------------------Fonction check pour remplir O--------------------------
int* Remplissage_O(float A[], int *O) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
        O[i]=A[i] >= 0;
    }
    return O;
}

//--------------------------Fonction Correction W --------------------------
void Correction_W(int *O, float *W, int X[ligne][colonne], int d[ligne], float epsilon, int index){
    for(int j=0;j<colonne;j++){
        W[j]=W[j]+(epsilon*((d[index]-O[index])*X[index][j]));
    }
}

//--------------------------Fonction Correction--------------------------
void Correction(float *A,float *W, int X[ligne][colonne], int *O, int d[ligne], float epsilon){
    int stop=0;
    int allCorrect= false;
    A=Remplissage_A(A,W,X,0);
    O=Remplissage_O(A,O);
    while (!allCorrect){
        for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
            if(d[i]!=O[i]){
                Correction_W(O,W,X,d,epsilon, i);
                A = Remplissage_A(A,W,X,i);
                O = Remplissage_O(A,O);
                stop++;
            }
        }
        if(stop==0){
            allCorrect=true;
        }
        stop=0;
    }
}

int main (){
    //--------------------------creation A, W, O, d, X, epsilon--------------------------
    float epsilon    =   0.2;
    int   O[ligne];
    float A[ligne];
    float W[colonne];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < colonne ; i++ ) {
        W[i]=rand() % 6;
    }
    int   d[ligne]   =   {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
    int   X[ligne][colonne]= {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1}};

    //--------------------------Affichage X--------------------------
    for(int i=0; i<colonne; i++){
        printf("X%d\t",i);
    }
    printf("Valeur\n");
    for(int i=0; i<ligne; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<colonne; j++){
            printf("%d",X[i][j]);
            if(j<colonne-1)
                printf("\t");
            else
                printf("    =>   %d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //--------------------------Print A et O et d--------------------------
    printf("\nA\t");printf("O\t");printf("D\n");
    float *Ax= Remplissage_A(A,W,X,0);
    int *Ox= Remplissage_O(A,O);
    for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
        printf(
           "%.1f\t"
           "%d\t"
           "%d\n",
           *(Ax + i),
           *(Ox + i),
           d[i]
        );
    }

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    //--------------------------Appel Fonction--------------------------
    Correction(A,W,X,O,d,epsilon);
    //--------------------------Apres correction--------------------------
    printf(
        "Apres correction : \n"
        "-----------------------------------------------\n"
        "\nA\t"
        "O\t"
        "D\n"
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++){
        printf(
           "%.1f\t"
           "%d\t"
           "%d\n",
           *(A + i),
           *(O + i),
           d[i]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested functions is a GCC extension on by default. I sorely miss it on Windows when I have to use MSVC.

Comment: @Joshua As used here the closures makes it different than normal c code.